# Shorthand attribute in each block of Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I have a JSON variable which contains attributes in the following manner:

```
// JSON variable defining attributes for elements to be created

let myElements = [
    {
        attr1: "myAttr1",
        attr2: "myAttr2",
    },
    {
        attr1: "myAttr4",
        attr2: "myAttr5",
    }
];
```

I want to render HTML elements based on the attributes defined in the JSON variable using the each block as shown below:

```
<-- Svelte Code -->

{#each myElements as myElement}
    <div {myElement.attr1} {myElement.attr2}>
    </div>
{/each}
```

So that they will be rendered in this way:

```
<-- Desired Resultant HTML -->
<div attr1="myAttr1" attr="myAttr2"></div>
<div attr1="myAttr4" attr2="myAttr5"></div>
```

However, svelte shows an "Expected a }" error when I refer to attributes like `{myElement.attr1}` in an HTML tag. Is it possible to use the shorthand attributes in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use deconstruction

```
<script>
    let things = [
    {attr1:'a',attr2:'b'},
        {attr1:'ace',attr2:'bdd'},
        {attr1:'as',attr2:'bsd'},
    ]
</script>

{#each things as {attr1, attr2}}
    <div {attr1} {attr2}>{attr1}</div>
{/each}
```

Comment: Yep, that works! Thanks a lot. Is it also possible to combine deconstruction with a normal object iteration? Suppose there are a lot of attributes, can I deconstruct a subset of them or do I have to deconstruct all of them?

Comment: You can deconstruct a subset afaik. Moreover, it is easily checkable.